# Sum of power tower which tends to $1$

Tags: inequality, lambert-w, power-towers

Inspired by an inequality of Vasile Cirtoaje, I have this :

> > Let $0<x<1$ then :
> >     $$x^{2(1-x)}+(1-x)^{2x}\leq 1$$
> >     Let $0<x<1$:$$f(x)=x^{1-x+x^{1-x+x^{2 (1-x)}}}$$
> >     Then :
> >     $$f(x)+f(1-x)\leq 1$$

We can create like this a power tower which tends to $1$. But be careful about the fact that $n$ is an odd or even number .

I try to use the Lambert function but it doesn't solve my power tower .

The main remark is that when $n$ tends to infinity, the terms of the inequality tend to $x$ and $1-x$.

If you have a nice ide,a thanks in advance to share it .